# MATLAB: getting rid of a for loop

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vectorization

I'm looping over a vector and calling a function for every element in it
I want to get rid of the loop, I can't see how.
**a short description about the code:**
I have `imageA` and `ImageB`, I want to map `ImageB` into `ImageA` where the user chooses 4 points in `ImageA` that locates the position of the pattern (`ImageB`)

**this is the part of code that has the for loop**

```
newIm=im1; % newIm will have the mapped image
[r,c]=size(im1); %size of imageA

[p1,p2]=meshgrid(1:c, 1:r); % using indexes matrixes 
% p1 has the X indexes 
% p2 has the Y indexes

z = ones(r,c); % a vector of ones (for mapping algorithm)

% now calculate for every point in imageA the indexes for its new value
% from imageB    ( Inverse Mapping)

% X         a b e   X'
% Y  = pinv c d f * Y'
% 1         g h 1   1

newmatrix=pinv(mat)*[p1(:) p2(:) z(:)]'; 
newX=newmatrix(1,:)./newmatrix(3,:); % devide the x with z
newY=newmatrix(2,:)./newmatrix(3,:); % devide the y with z
newX=round(newX);   
newY=round(newY);

% %% the indexes we want are the ones in the range  of ImageB 
Xindex=(newX<Br & newX>1); % this gives us a vector of zeros and ones
Yindex=(newY<Bc & newY>1); 
ourPixels=Xindex(:).*Yindex(:); % gives us a vectors that has ones
%  in the places where the Y and X are both in the range

ourIndexes=find(ourPixels==1); % a vector that holds the indexes that we want
IndexesSize=size(ourIndexes); 
XXX=newX(ourIndexes); %the indexes we want
YYY=newY(ourIndexes);

% loop the quadrilateral and "paint" it (only looping the quadrilateral
% and not the whole image)


for i=1 : IndexesSize(1)
    newIm(ourIndexes(i))=BilinearInterpolation(im2,YYY(i), XXX(i));
end

fprintf('press any key to see the result...');
pause;

imshow(newIm);
title('The new mapped Image');
```

**this is the function**

```
function NewVal=BilinearInterpolation(imgB,x,y)

% inpust: ImageB- the pattern image
% x and y the coordinates that locates the inverse mapping
% returns the new color of a spicifc pixel (x',y') in imageA


% SW SE NE NW are neighboors of (x,y) which will give us the new color


SW=imgB(floor(x),floor(y)+1);
SE=imgB(floor(x)+1,floor(y)+1);
NE=imgB(floor(x)+1,floor(y));
NW=imgB(floor(x),floor(y));


% the equations are the same as in the lecture
% S = SE * delta(x) + SW*(1- delta(x))
% N = NE * delta(x) + NW*(1- delta(x))
% V = N * delta(y) + S*(1 - delta(y))

deltax=x-floor(x);
S=SE*deltax+SW*(1-deltax);
N=NE*deltax+NW*(1-deltax);

deltay=1-(y-floor(y));
NewVal=N*deltay+S*(1-deltay);
end
```

I tried this:

```
newIm(ourIndexes)=BilinearInterpolation(im2,YYY, XXX);
```

but of course it didn't work
I tried changing the function to work with (`.*`) but also had a lot of problems

Comment: Just to clarify, is (1) the code painfully slow and you're trying to speed up by vectorizing or (2) have you joined the anti for loop MATLAB cult? This matters because it clarifies whether the ultimate goal is to make it faster or remove the for loop.

Comment: i don't want the loop at all… we are not allowed to use loops

Comment: I don't know what this `delta(x)` stuff is, but it looks like you can make your function so `BilinearInterpolation(im2,YYY, XXX)` gives you something useful. Switch `N*deltay` to `N.*deltay` etc...

Comment: i tried it, the matlab got crazy when i did it i switched every (.) to (.*).. didn't work

Answer (score 1):

With a little modification you can make your function accept an array of points.

Firstly as mentioned in the comments change your `*` to elementwise multiplication `.*`.

Also you'll need to change the times where you access imgB so that it will accept a list of points. Inputting two vectors (i.e. using the code unchanged) will call all combinations of those points i.e nxn points. Normally I would just use a for loop to avoid this as I am lazy and rarely need to optimise my code that much.

As you specifically don't want to use a loop, the easiest way I know to do this is to replace the calls to the subscripts with the appropriate linear indices using [sub2ind](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html). For example, `SW=imgB(sub2ind(size(imgB),floor(x),floor(y)+1));`

Other than that check that all your vectors have the same long dimension, I think they should but it depends on your input.